# Implementing Foldable[List[A]]

Tags: scala

I'm working on a [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) exercise to implement `List[A]` on the following trait.

```
trait Foldable[F[_]] {
    def foldRight[A, B](as: F[A])(f: (A, B) => B): B
    def foldLeft[A, B](as: F[A])(f: (B, A) => B): B
    def foldMap[A, B](as: F[A])(f: A => B)(mb: Monoid[B]): B
    def concatenate[A](as: F[A])(m: Monoid[A]): A = foldLeft(as)(m.zero)(m.op)
}
```

In my attempt to implement `foldLeft`, how can I specify an `initial` value if there's none in the signature?

```
trait Foldable[List[_]] {
    def foldLeft[A,B](as: List[A])(f: (A, B) => B): B = {
        go(bs: List[A], acc: B): B = bs match {
            case x :: xs => go(xs, f(x, acc))
            case Nil => acc
        }
    go(as, ???) // No start value in the signature? And no Monoid for m.zero
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you're missing some code. Your `concatenate` function has 3 curried parameters while `foldLeft` mentions only 2. In any case, for a `fold` to succeed, it needs three things: a starting list, a starting item (or a zeroth item) and a reducing/folding function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an error in the book. Take a look at the source on github and you'll see a zero method param:

https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala/blob/master/exercises/src/main/scala/fpinscala/monoids/Monoid.scala#L84

```
trait Foldable[F[_]] {
  import Monoid._

  def foldRight[A, B](as: F[A])(z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B =
    sys.error("todo")

  def foldLeft[A, B](as: F[A])(z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B =
    sys.error("todo")

  def foldMap[A, B](as: F[A])(f: A => B)(mb: Monoid[B]): B =
    sys.error("todo")

  def concatenate[A](as: F[A])(m: Monoid[A]): A =
    sys.error("todo")

  def toList[A](as: F[A]): List[A] =
    sys.error("todo")
}
```

Comment: When implementing `Foldable[List]`, what is its signature? I tried `trait Foldable[List]`, but got a compile-time error that such a trait already existed.

Comment: Take a look at the version in the source, they use an object: https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala/blob/master/exercises/src/main/scala/fpinscala/monoids/Monoid.scala#L103

Comment: thanks, Noah. Also, I get multiple `Foldable.scala:15: error: not found: type F` compile-time errors when using the `F[A]` as per the above signatures.

Comment: I just pulled and compiled their code and it seems to work fine.